# Can we use setTranslation() in angular 1.5?? If YES,explain how to use, If NO, is there any similar function to achieve in angular 1.5

Tags: angularjs

this.$translate.getTranslationTable("en-us") is working in my code
but  _this.$translate.setTranslation('en',{translateKey:_this.editFieldType.properties.labelName},true);
 is throwing an error

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the i18n for angular 1.5

I use [Angular Translate](https://angular-translate.github.io/) too to translate which is really useful and easy to use

with just the below code you can get the i18n (and i10n too) to translate your angularjs app

```
var app = angular.module('at', ['pascalprecht.translate']);

app.config(function ($translateProvider) {
  $translateProvider.translations('en', {
    TITLE: 'Hello',
    FOO: 'This is a paragraph.',
    BUTTON_LANG_EN: 'english',
    BUTTON_LANG_DE: 'german'
  });
  $translateProvider.translations('de', {
    TITLE: 'Hallo',
    FOO: 'Dies ist ein Paragraph.',
    BUTTON_LANG_EN: 'englisch',
    BUTTON_LANG_DE: 'deutsch'
  });
  $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
});

app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope, $translate) {
  $scope.changeLanguage = function (key) {
    $translate.use(key);
  };
});
```

I hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: is it possible to use $translateProvider in controller??

Comment: I want to update the $translateProvider.translations() dynamically